# Swift - scale background while retaining top anchor

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

How can I `scale` a `UIImageView` while retaining the top anchor?

I tried:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.backGroundImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        self.backGroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        self.backGroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    })
```

That scales the image but the anchor point is the middle of the image. It seems like setting the `topAnchor` doesn't do anything. Is there a way to set some sort of "scaleAnchor" or some other solution? 
In the end I would like to achieve this:

[image]

***Update***

This is how I `constrain` the `view`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // constrain background image
        backGroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        backGroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        backGroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        backGroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor), )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in **Swift 5.1**:

```
public extension UIView {

    func applyTransform(withScale scale: CGFloat, anchorPoint: CGPoint) {
        let xPadding = (scale - 1) * (anchorPoint.x - 0.5) * bounds.width
        let yPadding = (scale - 1) * (anchorPoint.y - 0.5) * bounds.height
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale).translatedBy(x: xPadding, y: yPadding)
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
yourView.applyTransform(withScale: 3, anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The transform matrix is applied *after* the frame has been calculated from the constraints.  If you want to scale things up consistently I suggest just setting a multiple on the height and width constraints instead.  Alternatively you can move the anchor point by using [CALayers.anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint) and then apply you transform so that it scales from the top middle instead of the center (which is the default).

EDIT -- example:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

class V: UIViewController {
  let square = UIView()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    square.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    square.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(square)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      square.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      square.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
      square.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
      square.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    ])
    square.layer.anchorPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0)
  }
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
      self.square.transform = .init(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
    }
  }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = V()
```

Comment: how do I move the anchorPoint to the top middle? :) that seems like the easiest way to do it

Comment: added an animated example to show that its growing from the top middle.

Comment: I added `self.backGroundImage.layer.anchorPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0)` but that cuts the image in half ?? I feel like I am doing something wrong with my constraints as I constrain it in `Main Storyboard`

Comment: changed it so everything is done programmatically now but that didn't change anything. Picture is still cut in half